# ¿Cómo me deshago de las líneas duplicadas donde un elemento es un diccionario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Tengo una dataframe con duplicados:

```
  Constituency                                           segments
0        Ahlaf  {'UND': {'I don't know yet': 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes...
1        Ahlaf  {'UND': {'I don't know yet': 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes...
2        Ahlaf  {'UND': {'I don't know yet': 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes...
3        Ahlaf  {'UND': {'I don't know yet': 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes...
4        Ahlaf  {'UND': {'I don't know yet': 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes...
...
```

y traté de deshacerme de ellos con:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Constituency', 'segments'], inplace=True) # necesito otras cosas
```

Pero me conteste el compilador que los diccionarios no son unashable:

```
  File "geojson_file_updater.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
  File "geojson_file_updater.py", line 57, in main
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Constituency', 'segments'], inplace=True)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4811, in drop_duplicates
    duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4888, in duplicated
    labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(f, vals)))
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4863, in f
    vals, size_hint=min(len(self), _SIZE_HINT_LIMIT)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 636, in factorize
    values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, size_hint=size_hint, na_value=na_value
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 484, in _factorize_array
    uniques, codes = table.factorize(values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, na_value=na_value)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1815, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1731, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que alguna de tus columnas o ambas son diccionarios Python (`dtype object`). Pandas para eliminar duplicados sigue una de las estrategias más eficientes que hay, tablas hash.

Para ello es imprescindible que el objeto sea hashable, es decir, que se pueda obtener un hash único que lo represente inequívocamente. Uno de los requisitos obvios es que el objeto sea inmutable, cosa que ocurre con todos los tipos nativos de Pandas, pero no con todos los objetos que pueden existir en Python.

Ésta es la causa también de que un diccionario o una lista no puedan ser claves de un diccionario ni items de un conjunto:

> ```
> >>> lista = [{"a": 4}, {"b": 5}, {"b": 5}]
> >>> sin_duplicados = set(lista)
>
> Traceback (innermost last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'    # <<<<<<<<<<
> ```

en cambio si las tuplas:

> ```
> >>> lista = [("a", 4), ("b", 5), ("b", 5)]
> >>> sin_duplicados = set(lista)
> >>> sin_duplicados
> {('b', 5), ('a', 4)}
> ```

En tu caso podemos reproducirlo fácilmente con el siguiente DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Constituency': ({"key1": "aaa", "key2": "bbb"},
                      {"key1": "aaa", "key2": "bbb"},
                      {"key1": "aaa", "key2": "bbb"}, 
                      {"key1": "aaa", "key2": "bbb"}
                      ), 
     'segments': ({"key3": 111, "key4": 333},
                  {"key3": 111, "key4": 222}, 
                  {"key3": 111, "key5": 222}, 
                  {"key3": 111, "key4": 222}
                   )})
```

> ```
> >>> df
>                      Constituency                    segments
> 0  {'key1': 'aaa', 'key2': 'bbb'}  {'key3': 111, 'key4': 333}
> 1  {'key1': 'aaa', 'key2': 'bbb'}  {'key3': 111, 'key4': 222}
> 2  {'key1': 'aaa', 'key2': 'bbb'}  {'key3': 111, 'key5': 222}
> 3  {'key1': 'aaa', 'key2': 'bbb'}  {'key3': 111, 'key4': 222}
>
>
> >>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Constituency', 'segments'], inplace=True)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
>     df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Constituency', 'segments'], inplace=True)
>   File ".pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4909, in drop_duplicates
>     duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
>   ...
>   File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1798, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize
>   File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1718, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' con el siguiente DataFrame:
> ```

### La solución

Lo óptimo sería evitar a toda costa tener columnas de tipo object. Lo apropiado sería desempaquetar esos diccionarios en columnas con tipos nativos de Pandas/NumPy si es posible, no solo por ésto, sino porque perdemos gran parte de lo que nos ofrece Pandas en terminos de eficiencia y vectorización de operaciones.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Constituency': ({"key1": "aaa", "key2": "bbb"},
                      {"key1": "aaa", "key2": "bbb"},
                      {"key1": "aaa", "key2": "bbb"}, 
                      {"key1": "aaa", "key2": "bbb"}
                      ), 
     'segments': ({"key3": 111, "key4": 333},
                  {"key3": 111, "key4": 222}, 
                  {"key3": 111, "key5": 222}, 
                  {"key3": 111, "key4": 222}
                   ),
      'foo': (1, 1, 1, 1)})



df = pd.concat([
    df.drop(['Constituency', 'segments'], axis=1),
    df['Constituency'].apply(pd.Series), 
    df['segments'].apply(pd.Series)], 
    axis=1)
df.drop_duplicates(
    subset=("key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5"), inplace=True
    )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    foo key1 key2   key3   key4   key5
> 0    1  aaa  bbb  111.0  333.0    NaN
> 1    1  aaa  bbb  111.0  222.0    NaN
> 2    1  aaa  bbb  111.0    NaN  222.0
> ```

Lo no óptimo es aprovecharnos de lo ya comentado, convertir los diccionarios en un objeto hashable y convertir en tupla la vista `dict.items` es lo que necesitamos:

```
filas_dupl = (df[["Constituency", "segments"]]
    .applymap(lambda dicc: tuple(dicc.items()))
    .duplicated()
    )
df = df[~filas_dupl]
```

> ```
> >>> df
>                      Constituency                    segments
> 0  {'key1': 'aaa', 'key2': 'bbb'}  {'key3': 111, 'key4': 333}
> 1  {'key1': 'aaa', 'key2': 'bbb'}  {'key3': 111, 'key4': 222}
> 2  {'key1': 'aaa', 'key2': 'bbb'}  {'key3': 111, 'key5': 222} # !=key5 no key4
> ```

Answer (score 1):

No claro, los diccionarios entre otros objetos no son "hashables", cosa que es requisito para `drop_duplicates()`, pero podrías convertirlos a un cadena y a partir de la misma buscar los duplicados, obtener las posiciones y hacer un subconjunto final para quitarlos:

```
no_dup_idx = df[['Constituency','segments']].astype(str).drop_duplicates().index
df = df.iloc[no_dup_idx]
```

Comment: Si me ! disculpe, voy a puestar mi question al dia